# What makes Oracle SOA Suite 12 JAR unable to recognize the JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, java-8, soa-suite

I am trying to install Oracle SOA Suite 12 on Windows 10. I set the JAVA_HOME correctly (able to `echo` it), and then trying to run the JAR. It gives me the following message:

`This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161 is not a valid JDK Java Home.`

It seems to look for the JRE folder and by default neglecting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. I did a workaround by navigating to the JDK folder, and then running the java.exe inside the JDK folder (java.exe -jar /path/to/soasuite). It works well. I just want to know what might be the reason.

Comment: you need to install a JDK, not a JRE (they are not the same) go to the [JDK download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and install the proper thing

Comment: it's already installed and the JAVA_HOME is set to point to it

Comment: then you need to fix the PATH, put C:\path\to\jdk\BIN as the first part of your PATH

Comment: No it isn't. It is set to point to a JRE. Fix that and you are done.

Comment: @EJP ... echo %JAVA_HOME% --> 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161

Comment: It is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161` in the environment the program was executed in. The error message does not lie.

Comment: this echo result is from the same environment

Comment: Err, no it doesn't, obviously, otherwise it would work, wouldn't it, and not display a different JAVA_HOME value. Examine your assumptions.

Comment: Just do this on your environment: `set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;%PATH%` before trying the installation and stop strugling

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to set the properties as follow. Adapt correctly to your path in the JAVA_HOME property, and the others will follow.

```
JAVA_HOME := C:\java\jdk1.8.0_151
JDK_HOME := %JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME := %JAVA_HOME%\jre
CLASSPATH := .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
PATH := %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

EDIT:

> I did a workaround by navigating to the JDK folder, and then running
>   the java.exe inside the JDK folder (java.exe -jar /path/to/soasuite).
>   It works well. I just want to know what might be the reason.

This means that you are missing the change in the PATH environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to utilize the path variables described - did not want to restart the machine durng and install of oracle software.  I was able to successfully complete the install of weblogic oracle fusion by doing the following.

RUN JAR files using command prompt due to having issues running the java installed setups for oracle12c, weblogic ,etc.

RUN command prompt as adminsitrator:
1. CHANGE DIRECTORY IN COMMAND PROMPT TO:
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

2. RUN the command like this - pointing to the proper JAR file.
   java -jar c:\oracleformssoftware\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_infrastructure.jar

This definately worked for me but please note I did finally setup the path variables instructions noted here.